# In Javascript, is function foo() { } a class, a standard function, or a function with properties?

Tags: javascript

As a newbie, function foo() { } confuses me.

Why is it used with so many purposes? What is it built for? Doesn't this make maintenance of code difficult?

edit: I'm not talking about "foo" but about functions in general.

Comment: It's an example. It's not actually working code. There is `bar()` too :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you ask if a function makes "maintenance of code difficult"? Wouldn't code be harder to maintain without functions?

Comment: Classes are becoming a bit more distinct in the next version of JavaScript. The combination of purposes is indeed a bit weird.

Comment: Its hard to know if this is a serious question  :) On the assumption that it is, Mark Zucchini is correct and foo is used as a sample name for any function/ class etc. If its not a serious question, well it actually makes things easier because you only have to look in one place for any problems- `foo()`  or perhaps `bar()` but in my experience it always `foo`!

Comment: I don't understand how general functions(as your edited question suggests) confuses you, so that you think it has many purposes. Do you want to know what functions are for? or how functions don't make your code hard to maintain ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you seem to be asking whether code is harder to maintain when functions are used for modules, functions, constructors, generators, and tons of other things. That's a fair question. Some may say yes, but many would say the language is simpler and more elegant because a single construct, the function, can do so much. It's no accident that Lisp and Smalltalk have some of the most passionate fans because those languages have a very simple core. JavaScript kind of has that simple core, but has a lot of other baggage, which you can read about in several places on the web.

But you also asked if a function *was a class*. Here's the deal: JavaScript does not have classes! It is best *not to even think of classes* in JavaScript. There are probably hundreds of attempts to create class-like structures in JavaScript. JavaScript was designed around the concept of *delegation* via prototypes.

Objects have prototypes. When you lookup a property in an object and the property is not present, the lookup is delegated to the prototype. That's it. Other languages like Self and Lua and Io have prototypes too (well Lua has metatables) but the point is: *these languages don't have classes and they don't need them*!

Now if you don't have classes and you want to make a bunch of objects of the same type, what do you do? You write a function that creates an object whose prototype holds the shared state and behavior for all the objects of that "type." Even in a language that has classes, the same kind of thing is going on---you have constructors (maybe called `new` or `init` or is named after the class or whatever).

Anyway, the answer to your question: "does not having classes make your program harder to maintain?" is "No, not when you learn how to use prototypes properly!"

It's ultimately a matter of preference, really. It is okay to prefer classes. It is okay to prefer prototypes. A good developer can use both.

Comment: Is the difference between normal classes and prototypes in JavaScript really meaningful in practice? Few applications take advantage of dynamic prototypal inheritance, they just use it to set a static class-like hierarchy. I'm glad that ES6 is finally optimizing for common use by just calling a class a class.

Comment: It's certainly true that most people use prototypes to simulate the kind of classes popularized by Java and C++. I use both JavaScript and CoffeeScript a good deal. CoffeeScript has classes---and even uses the word `class`---though a CoffeeScript class is, yes, just a function. And that's how ES6 classes are going to work (you can see it in Babel and the ES6 specs). Just surface syntax. Will it help? Sure, it could. I still think that writing class-less JavaScript isn't really less maintainable. But there is room for disagreement.

Answer (score -3):

As already stated in a comment, foo() is not an actual function. It is used to represent an example function. Function foo() can be anything else like f(), fun(), magic(), example().......You got the picture. When a funtion named foo() is used in working piece of code, it is made sure that the name is not used again. So it does not make maintenance difficult

Comment: I'm pretty sure (and hope) the OP isn't asking literally about "foo", but about functions in general.